# How to split XML values from a MySQL table?

Tags: mysql, xml

I'm using MySQL version 5.0. I want to split an XML value and insert the values into another table. Many people suggest using the `ExtractValue` function to get this split value, but when I use that function, it throws an error:

> FUNCTION ExtractValue does not exist

How can I fix this?

Here is my XML:

```
<Xml><Values><Value>1</Value><Value>2</Value><Value>3</Value></Values></Xml>
```

I want my result to be:

```
1
2
3
```

Comment: function ExtractValue is only available in >= MySQL 5.1.5

Comment: Thank you amdixon. Is there any possibilities to get this in MySQL 5.0.

Comment: without complex substring logic in sql, i think you should use your application logic for this

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are command line xml splitter tools you can call from your code, some are free.